# The A,I can't seems to move/strafe on the left continously?

Tags: unity, c#

```
 void Update()
{
    ChasingPlayer();
}

void ChasingPlayer()
{
    if (chasing == true)
    {
        transform.LookAt(player.transform);  //facing player
        transform.position += transform.forward * approaching * Time.deltaTime;  //going towards player
    }

        float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player.position);
    Debug.Log(distance); //calculating the distance between player and enemy
    if(distance < 10)
    {
        chasing = false;
        transform.position += Vector3.left * 2f * Time.deltaTime;
        Debug.Log("STOP!");
    }
}
```

I want my A.I to approach to the player but when it reaches within 10 feet(?), I want it to stop moving towards the player and strafe/move to the left or right from there but instead it just moving in a curve movement that leads towards the player. How should i stop the AI within 10 feet(?) and move to the left/right?

Comment: When/how do you set the `chasing` flag to `true`?

Comment: Note that an animated gif would help a lot get what's going on :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code reads

```
transform.position += Vector3.left * 2f * Time.deltaTime;
```

`Vector3.left` is a world-space direction; it does not take the enemy's current rotation into account. Perhaps what you want is this:

```
transform.position += transform.right * 2f * Time.deltaTime; //to go right
```

or

```
transform.position -= transform.right * 2f * Time.deltaTime; //to go left
```